# Import vs Bridging Header

Tags: ios, swift, compilation, cocoapods, bridging-header

Is there a compile time performance improvement when `import Foo` is used on top of a swift file instead of adding the library to the project through the bridging header using  `#import <Foo/Foo.h>?`